# Activemq can i set a propertie to a queue

Tags: properties, set, queue, activemq-classic

I have a question : In activeMQ, can I set a propertie to a queue ?
I know that I can set properties to a message, but is it possible also for a queue ?

For my use case, I would store a "last synchronisation date" into that queue that I could use each time I look for newest data in a database table. If the "update_at" column of my table is newer than the "last synchronisation date" of the queue, I send a message to the queue and update that "last synchronisation date" of the queue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would create a sync history table and put the  "last synchronisation date" in that table rather than trying to put it with Queue.

Comment: @basiljames Yes, that's probably what I will do. I wish I could let the queue bring that information by itself, without any external "tools", but it seems not possible. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The Queues themselves have no properties.  ActiveMQ does have support for several different destination filters and policy objects to control the behaviour of destination under a variety of circumstances and you can install your own broker plugins that you can use to extend the functionality but there is no properties model for the Queues themselves.